# How to get all the files from Applications document directory in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm new to swift language and i use this code for get document directory

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true);
```

it's right but when we run the project then the second cript code changed every time and my issue is that i want to store all the recorded videos to document directory and then load that all the recorded videos to my application's custom gallery to see the application's whole recorded videos but when i store that videos then it stores in different directory on every new run.

so how can i fatch and load that whole recorded videos from applications document directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do{
    let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory)
     for filename in files {
         print(filename)
    }
  }
     catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks can you give best and easy tutorial for that? and Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You haven't handled using try...catch